# Game Theory and Mr. Beast contest

Tags: game-theory

Mr. Beast held a contest in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e3GPea1Tyg&t=1295s

It goes something like where around 500 people compete in a contest to earn around $500,000.

At certain points in the video Mr. Beast offers people guaranteed money to drop out of the contest.

Sometimes I get confused about how game theory is applied in cases like this.

Is it "logical" (in game theory) for someone to drop out even if they are offered 1 dollar in the first round?

Or does it only make sense to drop out if your offered something proportionate to your chances of winning like \$1,000 (in the first round) (around \$500,000 / 500 people = \$1,000)

Comment: It makes sense depending on how risk-averse/risk-seeking you are. This can depend on your personality and your circumstances. For example, if you needed \$1000 for medicine, and was offered a payout of \$1000, you might decide (reasonably) to take it, instead of playing against one other person for \$3000. Assuming (probably falsely, in a game of skill) that each player has equal chance of winning, your expected earnings would be \$1500 for not taking the deal, but it would be a stupid risk when you could be guaranteed the money you need.

Comment: It depends how outcomes are valued. Obviously winning more money is better, but how much better? If you're playing the game repeatedly, it makes sense to try and maximize the expected value of your winnings. Expected value depends on your odds of winning the jackpot, which depends highly on the other contestants. 

If instead, like in the video, you only got to play once, it might be in your best interest just to assume that you'll lose and take the money. But it all depends on your personal motives and capabilities. 

Deciding on a specific simulation of the game would help a lot.